# LiveSmoother: payload size: 32768 exceeds maximum allowed

Tags: ffmpeg, srt

I'm using the ffmpeg with libsrt, I'm writing out a frame with [av_interleaved_write_frame](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.2/group__lavf__encoding.html#ga37352ed2c63493c38219d935e71db6c1), the url for the srt output is

```
srt://10.10.56.45:5555?mode=listener&mss=1316&pkt_size=1316&send_buffer_size=1316&ffs=1316
```

and I'm getting error

```
SRT.c: LiveSmoother: payload size: 32768 exceeds maximum allowed 1316
Operation not supported: Incorrect use of Message API (sendmsg/recvmsg)..
```

The packet I'm trying to write is larger than 1316, is this the cause of the problem? Shouldn't `av_interleaved_write_frame` take care of the big packets?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know yes `av_interleaved_write_frame` should've take care of formatting for internal operation like this. Anyway, you can also use SRT standalone with ffmpeg (https://github.com/Haivision/srt). If you can try ffmpeg+srt (external) and if it works, perhaps its better open a ticket on https://trac.ffmpeg.org.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer [here](https://gist.github.com/nxtreaming/defaf90d4a08fdda0a7b30440ddfbbaa), the pkt_size parameter was not taken.